# Не могу получить ссылки на картики Jsoup

Tags: jsoup, java

Здравствуйте. Решил освоить Jsoup, и для примера достать ссылки на картинки из Comicsbook'a. У меня получилось следующее:

```
public class ImageLoader {
    public static void main(String[] args){

        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

        Document doc=null;
        try {
            doc = Jsoup.connect("http://comicsbook.ru/?p=1").get();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("lol");
        }

        Elements link3 = doc.select("img[title][src$=.jpg]");

        for(Element el:link3){
            System.out.println(el.absUrl("src"));
            list.add(el.absUrl("src"));
        }   
    }
}
```

В результате получаю набор ссылок:

> http://comicsbook.ru/upload/Комикс-Другие-комиксы-Неприятный-момент-97136.jpg
> http://comicsbook.ru/upload/Прикол-Эти-разговоры-с-мамой-97135.jpg
> http://comicsbook.ru/upload/Комикс-Другие-комиксы-Правильные-советы-97108.jpg
> http://comicsbook.ru/upload/Комикс-Другие-комиксы-Неудачно-97110.jpg
> http://comicsbook.ru/upload/Комикс-Другие-комиксы-Крестовый-поход-97109.jpg
> http://comicsbook.ru/upload/Комикс-Другие-комиксы-Переиграл-в-Call-Of-Duty-97092.jpg
> http://comicsbook.ru/upload/Комикс-Другие-комиксы-Счастливая-история-(ну-почти)-97084.jpg

Но когда пытаюсь перейти по ним в браузере, открывается не сама картинка, а целая страница с ней. Почему так ? Или это защита такая?

Comment: я по ним попадаю на картинку :)

Comment: что же происходит... когда я ещё не открыл страницу с сайтом, и копировал адрес в броузер, то открывалась именно страничка. Если я побывал на странице, то открывается картинка. Магия.

Comment: Попробуйте скопировать ссылку и вставить её в другом броузере.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если в заголовках запроса указано значение для *Referer* (любое), то по вышеприведённым ссылкам открывается именно изображение. Если же *Referer* отсутствует - происходит редирект на соответствующую страницу comicsbook. Таким образом, вам необходимо при запросе добавлять это поле в заголовки.

Comment: Спасибо! Я бы сам никогда не додумался.